# PDO bind param value with variant

Tags: php, pdo

I am writing a query that gets an ID from the database where it's last digit can be 1-5. This works but seems messy. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

```
$id1 = $id.'1';
$id2 = $id.'2';
$id3 = $id.'3';
$id4 = $id.'4';
$id5 = $id.'5';

$sql = "SELECT col1
        FROM table1 
        WHERE id = :id1 OR id = :id2 OR id = :id3 OR id = :id4 OR id = :id5 
        LIMIT 1";      

$core = Connect::getInstance();

$stmt = $core->dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id1', $id1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':id2', $id2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':id3', $id3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':id4', $id4, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':id5', $id5, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: just use question mark placeholders then load em all up inside `->execute()`

Comment: @sounds not entirely sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$sql = "SELECT col1
        FROM table1 
        WHERE id = :id1 OR id = :id2 OR id = :id3 OR id = :id4 OR id = :id5 
        LIMIT 1";      

$core = Connect::getInstance();
$stmt = $core->dbh->prepare($sql);
for($i; $i<=5; $i++){
 $stmt->bindParam(':id'.$i, $id.$i, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use question mark placeholders. All the values, just load em all up inside the `->execute` method:

Question mark placeholders:

```
$sql = "SELECT col1
        FROM table1 
        WHERE id = ? OR id = ? OR id = ? OR id = ? OR id = ? 
        LIMIT 1";
```

Inside execute:

```
$stmt->execute(array($id1, $id2, $id3, $id4, $id5));
```